# Amazon S3 and retrieve specific object version via s3:// protocol in Apache Spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, versioning

According to the Amazon documentation I can retrieve the specific version of object via REST URL and specify the `versionId` parameter - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html

How to achieve the same via an `s3://` URI and specify the object version in Spark?

Comment: There is not really any such thing as an `s3://` protocol.   `s3://` is nothing more than a pseudo-scheme used by various tools to craft an S3 object URI, so how you might specify an object version in that format will depend on the tool in question (assuming it supports versioning).  Please provide that context.

Comment: I’d like to access the specific S3 object version from Apache Spark

Comment: Thanks, I've edited your question and tags accordingly.

Comment: Not in the Open source s3a connector (yet —patches with tests welcome); no idea about the closed source EMR one. It's tended to be ahead of the ASF one in the past, but less so these days, and you don't get to see what is happening inside.